# Autocorrelation with Replicates

Tags: regression, least-squares, autocorrelation

How to perform autocorrelation with replicates?
For each day I have many observations and I want to check wether these observations are correleated with the next day and the day after this day.

If if give the autocorrelation function my whole table as an input, observations within a day would be mistakenly considered as adjacent days with a time lag of 1.

My table looks like this:

[image]